# Project is missing required library

Tags: java, eclipse

I have read all the answers, and either I don't understand them or I try them and I still have the problem.

I get the message

```
Project 'Songbox' is missing required library: 
 'C:\Users\Owner\git\Songbox_10_25_19\Songbox\jar'  Songbox     Build path  Build Path Problem
```

The file does not exist; "Songbox_10_25_19" does not exist and has to reason to exist.  That was a snapshot of the project on 10/25/19 and is no longer relevant.  There is no place I can find in any of the project properties where I can find a reference to this directory.

I have done Clean builds, turned off automatic compilation, restarted eclipse, and this error still persists.  It has absolutely nothing to do with anything in the context of this project.

I am using eclipse 2019-09 on 64-bit Windows 10.

I did a search of all my files on my C: drive.  I found four references to Songbox_10_25_19.zip, but these are artifacts left over from last month's work.  If there is anything in the project that contains this string, it is not detected with file search.  So I have no explanation of how this name is appearing in my workspace.

[image: Build paths]

[image: Build paths]

Comment: In the _Libraries_ tab there is the item `Songbox/jar (class folder)`. If this item has been added by mistake, select it and click the _Remove_ button.

Answer (score 0):

Check Projects tab and if Songbox is not needed then remove it from the libraries and try again.

Comment: The project is called SongBox, so I thought it was needed.  Otherwise, I wouldn't get my files compiled.